# Detecting click in overflow menu in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

Is there any option to detect a click in overflow menu?

I don't want to detect clicking in particular items.

[image]

Comment: So you want the items there but not clickable? I think you need to be more precise with your purpose of this.

Comment: The only thing in the overflow are "particular items". If you do not want to detect clicks on those, there is nothing left.

Comment: @CommonsWare My UX designer want to know if someone clicked those three rectangles :)

Comment: I am not aware of a specific callback or anything that will be invoked just by tapping on that.

Comment: Try the solution at:
[Every time overflow menu is opened...u will get a callback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25117096/3382236) This might help u..

Answer (score 3):

As it was posted in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258906/detect-click-on-actionbars-overflow-menu-button), you can do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if(featureId == AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR){
        Toast.makeText(this, "OPEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if(featureId == AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR){
        Toast.makeText(this, "CLOSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
}
```

If you are inheriting from AppCompat. If not, the right constant to be used is `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR`

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to detect when the options menu itself is made visible? If so, I believe the "onPrepareOptionsMenu" method on Activity is your best bet.

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.
>
> The default implementation updates the system menu items based on the
>   activity's state. Deriving classes should always call through to the
>   base class implementation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

Comment: I don't know why but I could see this method called also on the activity creation... maybe it's a Sherlock only issue...

Comment: @ElhananMishraky Very well could be. I haven't used ActionBarSherlock personally. Instead I've had great success just using the compatibility libraries. But good note Elhanan, for those that are using ABS.

Comment: Actually I could distinguish the creation calls from user click calls by comparing the onPrepareOptionsMenu call time with the menu creation time. Thanks!