# Detect click on Actionbar's Overflow menu button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

Can I detect click/tap on the menu button of action bar, i.e. used to show overflow menu items?

By default it opens up the list with one item "Settings". Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

Until now it is detecting click on "2" but I want to detect click on "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Override FragmentActivity.onKeyDown

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (keyCode) {

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
        // Do Sometihng
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

To detect the click on the overflow menu have such code:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if(featureId == AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
        //overflow menu clicked, put code here...
    }
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    ...
}
```

To detect click on menu items, in case you have a menu like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu2" android:alphabeticShortcut="b"
        android:title="Menu No. 2" android:orderInCategory="2">
        <menu >
        <group android:id="@+id/group2" android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item android:id="@+id/submenu1" android:title="SubMenu No. 1" />
            <item android:id="@+id/submenu2" android:title="SubMenu No. 2" />
        </group>  
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

You should be able to detect the click in

> onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Log.w("ANDROID MENU TUTORIAL:", "onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)");

    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked: Menu No. 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;   
        ...
}
```

Comment: Answer is edited. You want to detect the click on the overflow menu, Android : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onMenuOpened%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29

Comment: If you use AppCompatActivity, then the constant is `AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR`. I was really going crazy with this one.

Answer (score 0):

By default clicking on the overflow button shows the options menu, so i believe you should manage to intercept the event, then do what you want by overriding `Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu`

This was a little tricky since i couldn't find an id for overflow button, so i used this hack.
In your `Activity` :

```
private boolean actionBarClicked = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getId() == )
        actionBarClicked = true;
    return false; // Let default processing occur
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    if (actionBarClicked) {
        // Overflow button of ActionBar was clicked, do what you want here.
        actionBarClicked = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is if (item.getId() == ) ? :)

Comment: Seems like null or an empty string is missing there

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup Toolbar and inflated menu correctly, just use these two function in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    //Perform some action on menu open
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    //Perform some action on menu closed
}
```

Setup toolbar in `onCreate` function of `MainActivity`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And inflate your menu which is defined in xml file

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**my_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_something"
        android:title="@string/something_text" />
    <!--Other menu items-->
</menu>
```