# What is the id of the menu overflow button(the button with three vertical dots)?

Tags: android

I want to know the id of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1bby.png) button. And is it possible to intercept its click method? And `KEYCODE_MENU` is not a solution to my question. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are dozens of examples of this. Do some research before asking please. Also, here in stackoverflow, write what you have tried, your code approach, and your research results for better answers. You are literally asking for someone to do you task.

Comment: Well provide me a link for one of the example than. because I know how to google and look for my answers and apparently i couldn't find it.

Comment: And i am not asking someone to bake a cookie for me, its more like i am asking the racipe.

Comment: don't this work for you ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258906/detect-click-on-actionbars-overflow-menu-button

Comment: No it didnt. :(